# Fetching string from webpage into C# Form application

Tags: c#, string, html

I want to set up a webpage with one small simple string on it. No images, no CSS, not anything else. Just a plain string that is not very long (maximum 20 char).

What is the best way to fetch this string with a C# Form application to use it for a variety of different purposes in the program, like showing people what the newest version of the software is when they boot it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use System.Net.WebClient myself like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.test.com");
    // TODO: do something with the downloaded result from the remote
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx):

```
        string remoteUri = "http://www.myserver.com/mypage.aspx";
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        string version = myWebClient.DownloadString(remoteUri);
```